# Calling an Amazon API with the AWS-SDK for Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to make a call to an Amazon API using the aws-sdk for node...I'm not sure if I'm using it the right way. I think I need to use the [ApiGateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/APIGateway.html) service.

Here is my constructor, but I'm not sure how to make a request to the api with this.

```
const apiGateway = new AWS.APIGateway(
      {
        apiVersion: '2015-07-09',
        accessKeyId: tempCreds.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: tempCreds.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
        sessionToken: tempCreds.Credentials.SessionToken,
        endpoint: config.preRegistration.baseUrl_US,
        region: 'us-east-1'
      }
    )
```

I was trying to do this without the sdk, but I was having problems with that too, so I decided to switch to the sdk since it handles signing the signature of the request.

```
  const opts = {
      service: 'execute-api',
      region: 'us-east-1',
    };

    aws4.sign(opts, {accessKeyId: tempCreds.Credentials.AccessKeyId, secretAccessKey: tempCreds.Credentials.SecretAccessKey});

      let response = await rp({
        method: 'POST',
        uri: config.preRegistration.baseUrl_US,
        opts,
        headers: {
          'x-amz-security-token': tempCreds.Credentials.SessionToken
        }
        body: load
      });
```

I'm basically just trying to make this simple POST request to an Amazon API, but getting the request built with all the temporary credentials and authorization has been really challenging for me.

Comment: All AWS SDKs have in-built request signing. You don't have to do it. Which AWS service are you actually trying to make a request to? API Gateway is an "API as a service" service - you use it in front of an API that *you* implement (typically with Lambda) - you don't use API Gateway when you want to call an AWS service such a EC2 or S3.

Comment: it's for a very specific, logistics API, but their documentation says to just use `execute-api` as the service. I can't find where to make calls with that in the SDK documentation

Comment: Which 'very specific, logistics API'?

Comment: what API of AWS you want to call? Which service? `API Gateway` is not the way to call AWS APIs.